# Automatic Car cannot drive forward, but will move in Reverse

Tags: brakes, tires, transmission, volvo, drivetrain

Hey so my car was serviced last Wednesday, got an oil change and replaced the brake rotors and pads. And it was driving fine all of Thursday and then for whatever reason late Friday the car would start to rumble when braking and the steering wheel would pull to the right slightly. Well I was already at a party so I didn't think much of it and was gonna go home and on Monday get them to look at it again as those aren't normal sounds a car would make. Anyways driving home I make a stop and now when I tried driving my car it would refuse to go forward like the front wheels would rotate two inches and then just refuse to rotate any more. Anyways I tried driving in reverse and it works albeit with the same rumbling sound that it has when braking. I am just wondering what the issue could have caused my front wheels to seize up. I did get it towed back to the shop I got the inspection at cause reasonably if they did an inspection and replaced the brakes for me you would expect the car to be perfectly fine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you put it in drive to go, does it feel like it wants to go, but just won't move?  What is the year/model of your Volvo?

Answer (score 0):

Without photos, we can only guess, but a plausible explanation is that the repair shop messed up when they replaced your pads and rotors. Brakes can fail in a way that the brake parts jam and prevent the car from moving forward but not reverse.

They may have installed the wrong model brake pads, or they may have re-assembled the brake calipers incorrectly, forgot to install critical parts, failed to properly torque the fasteners, or any number of other foulups.

It's possible that a new rotor has been damaged by the situation, so when you get the car back, be sure to look at the rotors, inside and outside, for scratches or gouges, especially on the right side of the vehicle.

If this is what happened, an ethical repair shop should admit their error and fix the problem free of charge, including new parts and labor, and should cover the cost of towing.

Be sure to turn on your BS detector when the shop tells you what the problem was, especially if they want you to pay for the repair.